# Display an add-in command button only if there are attachments

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js

I try to make an add-in command button to only be visible when there are attachments. Is it possible?

I expected I could add a "Rule" node to the "Control" node but it cannot be done:

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="hButton2">
    <Label resid="hButton2Label" />
    <Supertip>
        <Title resid="hButton2SupertipT" />
        <Description resid="hButton2SupertipD" />
    </Supertip>
    <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="h-button2-icon-16" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="h-button2-icon-32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="h-button2-icon-80" />
    </Icon>
    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
        <SourceLocation resid="hSourceLocation2"/>
    </Action>
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasAttachment" /> <-------------------- won't work
</Control>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Rule element is only applicable to the CustomPane extension point and can't be defined in a Control element: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/define-add-in-commands.  See also: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/activation-rules